# stop alert box from firing on every postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webform that displays an alert box when a searched for item is not found. the alertbox is all asp side, calling it is c# side in codebehind.

the issue is that after the first time it is called, it calls on every postback of the page. after the click it should not fire again until after another missed search.

i have tried `if(!ispostback)`, but the initial firing is a postback, so it won't fire at all.
during the postback it doesn't even call the c# code again, it just shows the alertbox.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .alertBox
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            left: 50%;
            width: 500px;
            margin-left: -250px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 4px 8px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function closeAlert(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.parentNode.style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form_rooftopSAQPM" runat="server">
    <div runat="server" id="AlertBox" class="alertBox" Visible="false">
        <div runat="server" id="AlertBoxMessage"></div>
        <button onclick="closeAlert.call(this, event)">Ok</button>
    </div>
...
```

```
        private void site_Load(string siteNumber)
        {
            DataSet ds = retrieveDataFromSQL("exec s_RooftopSite " + siteNumber, "Couldn't retrieve site information");
            if(ds.Tables.Count>0)
            {
                //load the fields
                txtFoo.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBoxShow("Site not found.");
            }
        }


protected void MessageBoxShow(string message)
        {
                this.AlertBoxMessage.InnerText = message;
                this.AlertBox.Visible = true;
        }

...
```

how can i set the alertbox to only fire when it is called by the c# code, yet still allow it to pop off on the first call, which is a postback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by switching from JavaScript to C#:

ASP:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnCloseAlert" 
     onclick="btnCloseAlert_Click" Text="Ok" />
```

CodeBehind in C#:

```
protected void btnCloseAlert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    AlertBox.Visible = false; 
    AlertBoxMessage.InnerText = "";
}
```